# Android - Scrolling within RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

The scroll view does not show the full text. It gets cutoff by couple of lines. 
I dont want to include the button in scrollview, it should always stay at the bottom. Any workaround for this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/details_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/provider_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:id="@+id/details_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/provider_logo"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_description"
                android:layout_below="@id/details_heading"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing andLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing andLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_grey"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/details_call_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add a `layout_above` attribute on your `ScrollView` with the `Button`'s ID. Also, you don't really need to specify `AppCompatButton` yourself. You can just use regular `Button`. It'll be taken care of during inflation.

Answer (score 1):

I added `android:layout_above="@+id/details_call_button` in **ScrollView** tag and it seems to work.